# Dynamic Priority change when adding multiple IP Restriction for App Services on Azure using terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure, azurerm-app-service

I'm looking a solution for changing the priority on a dynamic "ip_restriction"
the code that I use is

```
variable "ip_address_list" { 
  type = list 
  default = ["20.20.20.3/32" , "10.10.10.2/32"] 
}
```

```
site_config {
  dynamic "ip_restriction" {
for_each = var.ip_address_list
  content {
    ip_address  = cidrhost(ip_restriction.value, 0)
    action                    = "Allow"
    priority                  = 100
  }
}
```

When using this code I got the following output

> - ip_restriction= [
> - {
> - action= "Allow"
> - headers= (known after apply)
> - ip_address= "20.20.20.3"
> - name= (known after apply)
> - priority= 100
> - service_tag= null
> - virtual_network_subnet_id = null },
> - {
> - action= "Allow"
> - headers= (known after apply)
> - ip_address= "10.10.10.2"
> - name= (known after apply)
> - priority= 100
> - service_tag= null
> - virtual_network_subnet_id = null }, ]

Comment: Could you please add your variables.tf or how var.ip_address_list is defined?

Comment: Variable is defined as following: variable "ip_address_list" {
  type = list
  default = ["20.20.20.3/32" , "10.10.10.2/32"]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
locals {
 ip_address_list = [
           {     
                  ip_add : "20.20.20.3/32",
                  prior : "100"
            },
            {     
                 ip_add : "10.10.10.2/32",
                 prior : "101"
            }
     ]
}
```

and then

```
  site_config {
  dynamic "ip_restriction" {
for_each = local.ip_address_list
  content {
    ip_address  = ip_restriction.value["ip_add"]
    action                    = "Allow"
    priority                  = ip_restriction.value["prior"]
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Instead of declaring the variables you can declare the locals as given above and then use the site config block provided above.

**Update:** As per this [Github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3963) [@martinjt](https://github.com/martinjt) commented that it expects ipadd/32 as the subnet mask is not included in new versions . So, changed the above code by removing the `cidrhost` and did a apply it got deployed successfully.

**Error:** with `cidrhost`

[image]

After removing the `cidrhost`

[image]

Comment: This looks good but when I try to deploy I have error: Error: creating App Service "hook-service" (Resource Group "RG-DEV-TEST"): web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="IpSecurityRestriction.IpAddress is invalid.  '20.20.20.3' is an invalid CIDR!"}

Comment: also @Igor, can you Please try with `ip_restriction.value["ip_add"]` only instead of `cidrhost(ip_restriction.value["ip_add"], 0)` and let me know if it resolves the above  `'20.20.20.3' is an invalid CIDR!"}`

Comment: Thank you. I tested and it is deploying successfully.